# AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

iOS developer here thrown to the wolves of an Android project. I am getting a few error codes that all say something similar to `ThemeUtils: View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).` as soon as the following code snippet runs:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_basic_dashboard_screen, null, false)
```

My inflater is instantiated as follows:

```
val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(SqueaksApplication.getApplicationInstance())
```

`SqueaksApplication.getApplicationInstance()` just returns an instance of `public class SqueaksApplication extends Application`

Almost every answer I have found to this question points to the project's manifest as the issue and needing to provide a theme for the project. My project's manifest looks like the following:

```
<application
  android:name=".SqueaksApplication"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute"
  tools:replace="android:icon,android:allowBackup">
```

As you can see my manifest already includes the line `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

My project uses the layout inflator in many different places, but this is the only one I have come across that is throwing errors. Would appreciate any insight, or solutions you may have, thanks!

Edit: As requested this is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MainActivityTheme.Toolbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MainActivityTheme.ToolbarOverlay</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MainActivityTheme.Toolbar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MainActivityTheme.ActionOverflow</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#DE000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MainActivityTheme.ActionOverflow" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_settings</item>
</style>

<style name="MainActivityTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MainActivityTheme.ToolbarTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MainActivityTheme.ToolbarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MainActivityTheme.ToolbarTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#81be41</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ToolbarOverlay</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionOverflow</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionOverflow" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_white</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#81be41</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="squeak_item_popup_menu_animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/squeak_item_popup_menu_animation_enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/squeak_item_popup_menu_animation_exit</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: post your styles.xml or themes.xml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is the `context` used: `val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(SqueaksApplication.getApplicationInstance())`.

The `ApplicationContext` **doesn't have** your app theme.
You need to pass the `Activity`, not an Application Context.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to pass in an `Activity` correctly?

Comment: @ZacharyBell Are you inflating the view in an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: this is the class that I am in `class DashboardScreensAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), CoroutineScope {`

Comment: The class that it is manipulating is a `Fragment` it is `class DashboardScreensFragment : Fragment(), DashboardScreensAdapter.LoadingListener {`

Comment: @ZacharyBell In your Fragment you can use requireContext() for example.

Comment: thanks, it working for me